# Задать переменную php js

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите пожалуйста есть переменная js взятая из input. Как это значение поместить в переменную php?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var rowCount = $('#one').val();
  alert (rowCount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="one" value="10" type="text">
<?php
$pages="///Должно быть 10//";
echo "$pages";
?>
```

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js читать до полного понимания

Comment: Задать переменную php в js коде не получится. Сохраните значение переменной, сделав AJAX запроса

Answer (score 2):

php выполняется на сервере.
js выполняется в браузере у пользователя.
php ничего не знает про js и js ничего не знает про php.
Когда выполняется js, php уже отработал и умер.

```
<? $value=10;?>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="one" value="<?=$value;?>" type="text">
<?php
$pages=$value;
echo "$pages";
?>
```

Ну а значение 10 в переменной $value должно взяться допустим из базы данных или из cookies или из сессии.

Answer (score -1):

Как то так ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var rowCount = $('#one').val();
  alert (rowCount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="one" value="10" type="text">
<?php
$pages="<script>
let z = document.getElementById('one').value;
document.write(z);
</script>";
echo "$pages";
?>
```